# Bootstrap Modal only resets one time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap modal and bootstrap-modal extension with a form inside to do some function on a webpage, and I want to reset that form everytime I close the modal, this is the code I'm using:

```
<button class="btn <?php if (isset($_SESSION['useremail']) && $_SESSION['useremail'] == ""){ echo 'btn-default btn-sm btn-block';}else{ echo 'btn-primary btn-sm btn-block';}?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chgpwemail_modal" id="mailmanager" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['useremail']) && $_SESSION['useremail'] == "") echo 'disabled="disabled"';?>><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw" ></i>Alterar Senha Email</button>
```

After that the modal is fired and inside it I've got a dismiss button with this code:

```
 $('#dismiss-chgpwemail').click(function(event) {
     $('#chgpwemail_modal').modal('hide');
    });
    $.clearInput = function () {
      $('form').find('input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=number],input[type=email], textarea').val('');
    };
    $('#chgpwemail_modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {


    $.clearInput();

});
```

So my problem is following the clearInput() function only functions one time, after its used one time it doesn't work anymore.

And I can't figure out why, since after a complete page reload it does work again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do you can try this. Every time a modal is closed you'll try to find every form inputs and text areas and reset them.

```
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
     $('form').find('input').val('');
     $('form').find('textarea').html('');
});
```

Try to reformat the code better. I just noticed that what i typed its the same you have ;)

If you want to register this or every modal in your HTML you can do this: Instead of

```
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
```

Type this

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {.....});
```

With this you'll register the event for every modal you have. Don't forget that ".modal" is the reference for your modals. Replace it with yours.